# Finding currently logged in username Azure PowerShell (cloudshell)

Tags: azure-powershell

Using Azure CloudShell PowerShell I need to get the username of the user that is currently logged in. Not the subscription but the user (as appears in the top right).

Googling only brings up [signed-in-user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/signed-in-user?view=azure-cli-latest) which is a CLI command. [Get-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) doesn't seem to have a relevant flag.

Get-AzureRmContext provides the subscription rather than the username:

```
PS Azure:\> Get-AzureRmContext

Name                                     Account                                    SubscriptionName                           Environment                               TenantId
----                                     -------                                    ----------------                           -----------                               --------
my subscription 1                        a@b                                        my subscription 1                           AzureCloud                                <guid>
```

Where it says account it is definitely not the user i'm logged in with

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CloudShell, by default it uses MSI (managed identity). So, use Device Authentication & login first, then get account information as following:

```
Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication
(Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName (Get-AzContext).Account)[.Mail or .GivenName or .Surname]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
az account show --query user.name --output tsv

az ad signed-in-user show --query userPrincipalName -o tsv
```

The above commands will give you the email id of the current user

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, We can use the command `Get-AzureRmContext` to get the account which we use to login in Azure. The parameter "Account"  in the outputs will tell you the account you use to login. 
[image]

Besides, Azure Could Shell PowerShell uses MSI to login
 [image]

Comment: Thanks! i'm having the same MSI@ response but looking for the user I logged in with

Comment: Is that you want to know the user you use to login Azure Portal?

Comment: Yes, so that my script can record it

Comment: According to my test, if we use could shell PowerShell, we have no way to get username and password you used to login. Bescause it uses [MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) to complete Authentication with Azure.